# Old SSL certificate taking precedence over new certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, server, openssl, ssl-certificate

I recently inherited a website and ran into an issue with an expired SSL certificate. After verifying the certificate with OpenSSL, I discovered that there are two certificates for the one domain:

1. A manually created Let's Encrypt cert (expired)
2. A cert served by AWS's Certificate Manager (working)

The OpenSSL check points to the working cert when `www.` is  at the beginning of the URL, but if the `www.` is removed the check points to the expired cert. The weird issue is that the AWS cert is a wildcard cert for the domain, and does not contain a `www.` in it.

How can I resolve this issue to just have users directed to the correct SSL cert? I attempted to locate the actual cert file in the server in an attempt to remove it, but I couldn't find it in any of the usual places.

Comment: Is the website running behind a load balancer or something? If so then it could be that the load balancer has the old certificate attached to the HTTPS listener still which is linked to a record inside R53, that would be my first thing to check.  Without more info on the Infrastructure it's hard to tell where the cert could be placed.

Comment: There is only one certificate (the working one) listed in AWS/ACM. The server is running with a load balancer, but the HTTPS listener is pointing to that AWS certificate. Nowhere in AWS can I find any reference to this expired certificate. What's got me ripping my hair out is that I can't find the certificate anywhere on the server either, and I've checked everywhere from the Apache directory, to Let'sEncrypt/Certbot directory, to a dozen default SSL certificate locations.